# Protractor nested for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, protractor

I need some help with a nested for loop in protractor and converting/understanding promises correctly. In ‘test’ below the functionality works with all values, but as soon as I try to put in the nested for loops things go south. Any chance someone has a clean suggestion on this? I have tried the forEach which some indicate handle the promise issue inherently, but I seem to get the same results.

My Test data looks like:

```
objectPage.chartValues = {
[['chart','ChartID01'],['title','TitleText01'],['Name01','value01'],['Name02','Value02']],
[[‘chart','ChartID02'],['title','TitleText02'],['Name01','value01'],['Name02','Value02']],
[[‘chart','ChartID03'],['title','TitleText03'],['Name01','value01'], [‘Name02’,'Value02'],['Name03','Value03']]
}

it ('test', function (){

    for (chartNumber = 0; chartNumber < objectPage.chartValues.length; chartNumber++) {
        for (chartEntry = 1; chartEntry < ObjectPage.chartValues[chartNumber].length; chartEntry++) {

    //for readability of next call pulled out here
            chart = objectPage.chartValues[chartNumber][0][1];
            name = objectPage.chartValues[chartNumber][chartEntry][0];
            value = objectPage.chartValues[chartNumber][chartEntry][1];

            pageObject.getbackgroundcolor(chart, name).then(function (color) {
                expect(pageObject.getElementFromTable(chart, name, color).getText())
                    .toEqual(value);

            });
        }
    }
});

//function calls in pageobject  the call for get background is straight forward.

   this.getbackgroundcolor = function (chartName, valueName) {
             return element(by.id(chartName)).element(by.cssContainingText('.dxc-item', valueName)).element(by.tagName('rect')).getAttribute('fill');

//get element is very similar.
    this.getElementFromTable = function(chartName, valueName, colorname) {
    some searching stuff.. 
    return element(by.css(‘tspan'));
```

My results seem to indicate the look executes, but not returning from the actual expect. Finally trying to find a value for an item with background color of null. I know this is not true as I have run all values individually and in sequence without issue. Hopefully I avoided cut and past/generalization errors.

Thank you.

Update: 
        it('Verify Charts on page ', function () {

```
   myChartlength = objectPage.chartValues.length;

    for (chartNumber = 0; chartNumber < myChartlength; chartNumber++) {
        (function (chartNumber) {

            myEntrylength = objectPage.chartValues[chartNumber].length;           
            chartValues = objectPage.chartValues[chartNumber];

            for (chartEntry = 2; chartEntry < myEntrylength; chartEntry++) {
                (function (chartEntry) {

                    //pulled these out for readablility of next call.
                    chart = chartValues[0][1];
                    name = chartValues[chartEntry][0];
                    value = chartValues[chartEntry][1];
                    console.log('chart: ' + chart + ', name: ' + name + ', value: ' + value);

                  page.getbackgroundcolor(chart, name).then(function (color) {
                        expect(objectPage.getElementFromTable(chart, name, color).getText()).toEqual(value);
                    });
                })(chartEntry);
            };
        })(chartNumber);
    };
```

});

Comment: you should probably re-format your question - the code should be formatted as code. use the 'code' button :]

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) to me. If not, please fix that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, if I'm understanding your question correctly, your problem is async. It's firing through the loops before any promises are returned.

To loop tests, the best solution I've found is to use an `IIFE` ([Instantly Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)). In which, you create your loop, create the iife, and pass in the index.

Here's a basic example:

```
describe('to loop tests', function() {
    var data = ['1', '2', '3'];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // create your iife
        (function(i) { 

            it('pass in the index to an iife', function() {
                console.log('i is: ' + i);
                expect(data[i]).toBe(true); 
            });

        })(i); // pass in index
    }
});
```

This works great for data driving tests from say a data file, or whatever. And if you need multiple loops, like in your example code, you'll just make multiple iifes.

Comment: This worked for me. I will add edited code to original question as it is too long for comments. Thank you.

Comment: Glad this worked for you. You should mark this as the answer, to let other folks with the same issue know...

Comment: How would one do such a thing?

Comment: There should be a checkmark icon next to all the answers. The one you click turns green, and becomes the accepted answer :)

Comment: Done. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use for loops with protractor or you will have a bad time.
Due to the asynchronous nature of Protractor, if you need loops, I see `async's map` https://github.com/caolan/async  as one good and clean solution.

Other option is to use ES5's `map` when you need loops in Protractor, such as:

```
[1,3,5,7].map(function(index,key){
   expect(element.all(by.css('.pages-list')).get(index).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy()
})
```

In your case, I see that you need a `for loops` to produce array, that you later can map over it.

You can have this array with function, that uses `for loops` inside and returns the needed array to a callback.
Simple example with one `for loop`

```
function returnIndexes(callback){ 
var exitArray = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
     if(someArray[i].length > 12){
        exitArray.push(someArray[i]); 
     }

     if(i==someArray.length-1){
     callback(exitArray);
     }
}
```